# Why do programs allocate so much memory for simple commands?

Tags: ubuntu, memory

Valgrind reports that `whois` allocates a lot of memory even if I just ask for its version.

```
$ valgrind whois --version
==18086== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18086== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18086== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18086== Command: whois --version
==18086== 
Version 5.2.11.

Report bugs to <md+whois@linux.it>.
==18086== 
==18086== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18086==     in use at exit: 65 bytes in 1 blocks
==18086==   total heap usage: 56 allocs, 55 frees, 15,171 bytes allocated
==18086== 
==18086== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18086==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18086==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18086==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18086==    still reachable: 65 bytes in 1 blocks
==18086==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18086== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18086== 
==18086== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18086== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Experimenting with several other utilities, I found that this was common to many of them: they allocate a lot of memory for simple commands. Just look at gcc!

```
$ valgrind gcc --version
==18141== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18141== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18141== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18141== Command: gcc --version
==18141== 
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

==18141== 
==18141== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18141==     in use at exit: 116,660 bytes in 62 blocks
==18141==   total heap usage: 171 allocs, 109 frees, 135,692 bytes allocated
==18141== 
==18141== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18141==    definitely lost: 4,552 bytes in 13 blocks
==18141==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18141==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18141==    still reachable: 112,108 bytes in 49 blocks
==18141==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18141== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18141== 
==18141== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18141== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: So you think that whois should not use around 100 bytes of memory and gcc should not use so much as 135KB?  Really!?!?!  If you want to know what it does, just look at the source code.  Chances are you will not be able to reduce that without removing some functionality, even if you spend your life on learning to program to optimize that.

Comment: Emblem... why don't you try writing a "hello, world" program and see how much memory it allocates... even if you never make a malloc (or equivalent) call? As for gcc, do you have any clue how complicated compilers are?